# Adding helper class which uses "IHttpContextAccessor" should be Singlton or Scoped

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I am creating a class which reads the header using `IHttpContextAccessor` and reads the values from header.
Like ".net framework" we can access context in static manner `HttpContext.Current...` so shall I inject my class as Singlton or Scoped as the context or context.header value is going to change in each request.

Below is what I am trying

```
public class RequestHeaderHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;

    public RequestHeaderHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    } 
    public string BrowserIP
    {
        get
        {
            if (httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Client-IP"))
                return httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Client-IP").ToString();
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        private set { }
    }
    ....
}
```

### Edit 1

Further I am going to use this class inside my other classes like logger. I have created action filter and exception logger where I am going to use this.

I am also using `wcf client` class to call the service. I am using logging there as well using `beforesend and aftersend`. I am adding endpoint behavior.

I want to use `wcf client` as singlton but use the above class in logger.

Comment: [`IHttpContextAccessor` is registered as singleton](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27). The code as you've shown it should work whether you register your service as singleton or scoped.

Comment: All you need to do is `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` in Startup

Comment: @Chetan OP is asking what to register `RequestHeaderHelper` as.

Comment: Please provide reason for close vote.

Comment: I voted to close this because it's opinion-based.

Comment: @Llama do you think it may give any other context value due to adding the class singlton?

Comment: Singleton: it will probably make requests _marginally_ faster since the object won't have to be constructed each time. I say marginally since it's a very lightweight object anyway, and the only service it requires is already singleton so its instantiation time is probably insignificant. Scoped: would allow you to store some state information related to the current request (caching a value, for example). Alternative approach: make an extension method on `IHttpContextAccessor` or `HttpContext` to provide the information and just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and use the extension method.

Comment: As already pointed out `IHttpContextAccessor` is registered as singleton, the `RequestHeaderHelper` doesn't seem to be doing anything extra aside retrieving the info the singleton `IHttpContextAccessor` already has. So, there's no point registering `RequestHeaderHelper` as scoped.